# Determine if the original path of an alias is local or remote

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, command-line

I have a folder full of thousands of aliases and need to isolate the ones referencing a remote path on another computer on an AFP network. I can iterate all of the alias files over a terminal command with Automator but can't find the right command to determine the original path of an alias.

Is this automation possible?